# making css animation when in ViewPort

Tags: css, animation, viewport

if I change the class test to FadeInUp in all the instances where it say test the animation in the view port stop working when scrolling back up. the class im changing should have no other effect other than changing the name right??? 
 What am I doing wrong why does the div stop working when  in view port when changing all instances of test to FadeInUp????

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $animationElements = $('.animation-element');
  var $window = $(window);

  // ps: Let's FIRST disable triggering on small devices!
  var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 768px)");
  if (isMobile.matches) {
      $animationElements.removeClass('animation-element');
  }

  function checkIfInView() {

      var windowHeight = $window.height();
      var windowTopPosition = $window.scrollTop();
      var windowBottomPosition = (windowTopPosition + windowHeight);

      $.each($animationElements, function () {
          var $element = $(this);
          var elementHeight = $element.outerHeight();
          var elementTopPosition = $element.offset().top;
          var elementBottomPosition = (elementTopPosition + elementHeight);

//check to see if this current container is within viewport
          if ((elementBottomPosition >= windowTopPosition) &&
              (elementTopPosition <= windowBottomPosition)) {
              $element.addClass('in-view');
          } else {
              $element.removeClass('in-view');
          }
      });
  }

  $window.on('scroll resize', checkIfInView);
  $window.trigger('scroll');


  /* @end viewport trigger script  */

});
```

```css
/** ----//
*  @group standaard animaties
*  @author @david
*/

/* Trigger  */
.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  }

/* Optional Delays, change values here  */
.one { animation-delay: 0.2s; }
.two { animation-delay: .6s; }
.three { animation-delay: 1s; }
.four { animation-delay: 1.4s; }

/* Animations start here  */




/* FADE IN UP BIG */

@keyframes FadeInUp {
from { opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0); }
  to { opacity: 1; transform: none; } }
.FadeInUp { animation-name: FadeInUp; }


/* FADE IN LEFT BIG */

@keyframes FadeInLeft {
  from { opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0); }
  to { opacity: 1; transform: none; } }
.FadeInLeft { animation-name: FadeInLeft; }


@keyframes FadeInRight {
  from { opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(500px, 0, 0); }
  to { opacity: 1; transform: none; } }
.FadeInRight { animation-name: FadeInRight; }



/* @end standaard animaties  */
 body {
    overflow-x:hidden; /* hides scrollbar but does it cause other issues????*/
}

.callout {border: 1px solid green;
padding:10px;
  margin:0 auto;
text-align: center;
display:table;
}

.test.in-view {
   animation: FadeInUp;
    animation-duration: 3s;
   animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
.FadeInUp.in-view {
   animation: FadeInUp;
    animation-duration: 3s;
   animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
.test2.in-view {  
   animation: FadeInLeft;
    animation-duration: 3s;
   animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.test3.in-view {  
   animation: FadeInRight;
    animation-duration: 3s;
   animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* if it was SASS you could use: 
.test2.in-view {
     @extend .fadeInUpBig;
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
</script>
<style> 
</style>

</head>
<body>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="callout test animation-element">fade in from bottom</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="callout animation-element test2">fade in left</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="callout animation-element test3">fade in right</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="callout test animation-element">fade in bottom</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="callout animation-element test2">fade in left</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="callout animation-element test3">fade in right</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="callout test animation-element">fade in from bottom</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="callout animation-element test2">fade in left</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="callout animation-element test3">fade in right</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying that:

```
    if (isMobile.matches) {
        $animationElements.removeClass('animation-element');
    }
```

with that:

```
    if (isMobile.matches) {
        $(animationElements).removeClass('animation-element');
    }
```

Comment: It can be other errors, use Innspector (Developer Tool) to find other errors

Answer (score 0):

using lowercase for all classes fixes issue. Its trying to run the keyframe animation labeled with caps and not the class which includes the animation.

```
.fadeInup.in-view {
animation: FadeInUp;
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-fill-mode: both;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}


<div class="callout fadeInup animation-element">fade in from bottom</div>
```